# Appending Elements to a existing array within an array (2d array) - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am still new to PHP.

My problem:
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array

Description:
I have a list of room numbers that I am parsing. The first number of the room number refers to the floor of the room. I want to create a 2d array that holds floor numbers, and each floor consists of the rooms.

Code:

```
    $array = self::getAllRooms();
    $floorArray = array();
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        $floorNum = substr($row['room_no'],0,1);
        if (in_array($floorNum, $floorArray))
        {
            array_push($floorArray[$floorNum], $row['room_no']);
        }
        else 
        {
            array_push($floorArray, $floorNum);
            array_push($floorArray[$floorNum], $row['room_no']);
        }
    }
```

How do I append the room numbers to the "1" category referring to floor 1?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
$array = array(array('Stack','Overflow'));

$array[0][] = '.com';
// or
array_push($array[0],'.com');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stack
            [1] => Overflow
            [2] => .com
            [3] => .com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug here:

```
array_push($floorArray, $floorNum);
array_push($floorArray[$floorNum], $row['room_no']);
```

The first line pushes an element with a *value* of `$floorNum` into the array, but the second line expects an element with a *key* equal to `$floorNum` to be present.

You can do what you want much simpler:

```
foreach($array as $row)
{
    $floorNum = substr($row['room_no'],0,1);
    $floorArray[$floorNum][] = $row['room_no'];
}
```

Comment: Hi!
After trying to print the contents of the arrays i get "Array" instead of the floor number.

  foreach($floorArray as $row1)
  {
   echo $row1."<br>";
   foreach($row1 as $row2)
   {
    echo $row2;
   } 
  }

Comment: @AeroChocolate: Don't print arrays with `echo`. Use `print_r` instead: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($floorArray); echo '</pre>';`.